# Spring Rest `@Controller` wiered behaviour

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am trying hands on Spring Rest service via `@Controller`. But i came across situation where one method call is responding with valid data and other filtered method call returning incorrect response. Here is my `controller`

```
@Controller 
@RequestMapping("/company")
public class CompanyDetailsController {

@Autowired
private CompanyServices companyServices;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<CompanyDetails> getCompanyDetails() {
    return companyServices.getCompanyDetails();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{companyShortCode}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody CompanyDetails getCompanyDetails(@PathVariable("companyShortCode") String companyShortCode) {
    System.out.println("companyShortCode = "+companyShortCode);
    CompanyDetails companyDetails = companyServices.getCompanyDetails(companyShortCode);
    /*CompanyDetails companyDetails = new CompanyDetails();
    companyDetails.setCompanyCode("abc");
    companyDetails.setCompanyEmail("abc@123.com");
    companyDetails.setCompanyPhone(92349234);
    companyDetails.setWebSite("abc.abc.com");
    System.out.println("companyDetails = "+companyDetails);*/
    return companyDetails;
}
}
```

`CompanyDetails`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "company_details")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
public class CompanyDetails implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 8713608417980657723L;

@Id
@Column(name="COMPANY_CODE", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private String companyCode = null;

@Column(name = "COMPANY_NAME", nullable = false, updatable = true)
private String companyName = null;

@Column(name = "COMPANY_PHONE", nullable = true, updatable = true)
private long companyPhone = 0;

@Column(name = "COMPANY_EMAIL", nullable = true, updatable = true)
private String companyEmail = null;

@Column(name = "COMPANY_WEBSITE", nullable = true, updatable = true)
private String webSite = null;

public String getCompanyCode() {
    return companyCode;
}

public void setCompanyCode(String companyCode) {
    this.companyCode = companyCode;
}

public String getCompanyName() {
    return companyName;
}

public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
    this.companyName = companyName;
}

public long getCompanyPhone() {
    return companyPhone;
}

public void setCompanyPhone(long companyPhone) {
    this.companyPhone = companyPhone;
}

public String getCompanyEmail() {
    return companyEmail;
}

public void setCompanyEmail(String companyEmail) {
    this.companyEmail = companyEmail;
}

public String getWebSite() {
    return webSite;
}

public void setWebSite(String webSite) {
    this.webSite = webSite;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result
            + ((companyCode == null) ? 0 : companyCode.hashCode());
    result = prime * result
            + ((companyName == null) ? 0 : companyName.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    CompanyDetails other = (CompanyDetails) obj;
    if (companyCode == null) {
        if (other.companyCode != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!companyCode.equals(other.companyCode))
        return false;
    if (companyName == null) {
        if (other.companyName != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!companyName.equals(other.companyName))
        return false;
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "CompanyDetails [companyCode=" + companyCode + ", companyName="
            + companyName + ", companyPhone=" + companyPhone
            + ", companyEmail=" + companyEmail + ", webSite=" + webSite
            + "]";
}
}
```

`Repository`

```
@Repository
public class DetailsDaoImpl implements DetailsDao {

private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<CompanyDetails> getCompanyDetails() {
    List<CompanyDetails> details = (List<CompanyDetails>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(CompanyDetails.class).list();
    return details;
}

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public CompanyDetails getCompanyDetails(String companyShortCode) {
    System.out.println("companyShortCode = "+companyShortCode);
    CompanyDetails details = (CompanyDetails) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(CompanyDetails.class, companyShortCode);
    System.out.println("details = "+details);
    return details;
}
}
```

`Service`

```
public class CompanyServicesImpl implements CompanyServices {

@Autowired
DetailsDao detailsDao;

@Override
public List<CompanyDetails> getCompanyDetails() {
    return detailsDao.getCompanyDetails();

}

@Override
public CompanyDetails getCompanyDetails(String companyShortCode) {
    System.out.println("companyShortCode = "+companyShortCode);
    return detailsDao.getCompanyDetails(companyShortCode);
}

}
```

If I call `List<CompanyDetails> getCompanyDetails()`, It return -

```
[
  {
  "companyCode": "ABCD",
  "companyName": "Test Company",
  "companyPhone": 11226123456,
  "companyEmail": "abc@abcd.com",
  "webSite": "www.abc.com"
   },
  {
  "companyCode": "XYZA",
  "companyName": "XYZA Company",
  "companyPhone": 1122000000,
  "companyEmail": "abc@XYZA.com",
  "webSite": "www.XYZA.com"
   }
]
```

But when i call - `Public @ResponseBody CompanyDetails getCompanyDetails(@PathVariable("companyShortCode") String companyShortCode) {`, 
It return -

```
{"companyPhone": 0}
```

I tried with dummy Object and it makes it to Json. Tried Creating normal bean and not `@Entity` and used `BeanUtils` to copy properties and responding the correct Json. Anyone Know why this is happening?

**Updated**

before sending response, it is printing as `CompanyDetails [companyCode=ABCD, companyName=Test Company, companyPhone=9823611147, companyEmail=abc@abcd.com, webSite=www.abc.com]`

Comment: try changing `private long companyPhone` to `private Long companyPhone`

Comment: @Jobin but that should also not work for List api call or am i missing something. Will try n check both methods

Comment: Does it work with commented code?

Comment: @Surace yes. It Works with Commented code.

Comment: @Jobin tried `long` with `Long`, no success

Comment: Please provide your service or repository .

Comment: @David I tried your suggestion and for debug, printed the CompanyDetails till the return, everything is fine.

Comment: Can you post the code of the CompanyServices.getCompanyDetails(String companyShortCode) . I don't see a short code in the Company Class. With the commented code, you are assigning the attributes explicitly

Comment: show us your getCompanyDetails(companyShortCode), your companyShotCode is not giving you back the compay details it seems

Comment: @Amal `companyShorCode` is nothing by `companyCode`

Comment: There is a dao call. Does the table referred in detailsDao, have the data for the companyShortCode. If yes, try logging the value of detailsDao.getCompanyDetails(companyShortCode) in the service and check.

Comment: @David, In question, i already mentioned that If i use BeanUtils to copy properties then it returns the actual result. Without any modification, It is returning List of Company Details but Single filtered company details is problem. I printed the object before returning and all is well.

Comment: @Amal, as a developer i tried these option, before sending response, it is printing as `companyDetails = CompanyDetails [companyCode=ABCD, companyName=Test Company, companyPhone=9823611147, companyEmail=abc@abcd.com, webSite=www.abc.com]`

Comment: @Swaraj now show us your client side calling

Comment: @ScanQR for `List<CompanyDetails>` - `http://localhost:8080/myapp/company` and for Single Search Query - `http://localhost:8080/myapp/company/ABCD`

Comment: If you are getting result from service before sending the response I guess the problem is in your consumer side.

Comment: @David.. Is it something that I am responding with Dao entity and JSon message interpretation is messing something

Comment: Thank you all for help and efforts. It was not related to `Controller` but with hibernate `load` was proxy and not the actual object for outside the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `public CompanyDetails getCompanyDetails(String companyShortCode)` method when you are retrieving `CompanyDetails` object using its Primary Key `companyShortCode` you are using `load` method.

`load` method return a proxy object in which only Primary Key attribute is set and all other attributes are not set. Your `session` object will send query for retrieving the actual object only when you call any one of getter method for a attribute like `details.getCompanyEmail()`.

So for avoiding that you can call `get` method. See below code snippet:

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public CompanyDetails getCompanyDetails(String companyShortCode) {
    System.out.println("companyShortCode = "+companyShortCode);
    CompanyDetails details = (CompanyDetails) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(CompanyDetails.class, companyShortCode);
    System.out.println("details = "+details);
    return details;
}
}
```

If you want to go for load method then use below code snippet:

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public CompanyDetails getCompanyDetails(String companyShortCode) {
    System.out.println("companyShortCode = "+companyShortCode);
    CompanyDetails details = (CompanyDetails) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(CompanyDetails.class, companyShortCode);
    details.getCompanyName(); //after this all attribute of CompanyDetails object will be set
    System.out.println("details = "+details);
    return details;
}
}
```

For more reference see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22142920/what-is-difference-between-get-and-load-method-of-hibernate-session-with-res)

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Swaraj Did it work? or you want to stay with load method.

Comment: Yes it worked. `load` is converted to `get` in dao and got exactly i wanted.

Comment: If you want to stay with load just call `details.[anygetter]()` after load method call, your details object will be set with all attribute.

Comment: Yes.. I missed this point of Load and thought Json Message converter will call that by default.

Comment: Its okay. But now you know :)

Answer (score -1):

First of all the code is not completely posted, And I am not clear wi ththe response of the second call. The problem might be in the companyservices where you might be creating new object rather than fetching from JPA or from its underlying platform. Another cause might be the JPA configuration.

Comment: Added Missing Dao and Services classes

Comment: The problem was with the load api, as @sachinsarawgi said it will return only the proxy object, use get rather than load, your code will work.